# Recursively Querying Ways/Nodes Within a Building

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to query nodes and ways with specific properties (e.g., amenity=toilets) that are located within a building. Modeling this using an around query does work to some extent:

```
rel[wikidata=Q835662];
nwr(around:100)[amenity=toilets];
out geom;
```

I assume there is a better/more efficient way by recursively traversing the relations of the entities. A concrete example would be the following path:

[[wikidata=Q835662]](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4618821)
-> [Building: Way 329782196](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/329782196)
-> [Level: Way 372306562](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/372306562)
-> [Corridor: Way 374418922](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/374418922)
-> [Room: Way 374474150 with amenity=toilets](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/374474150)

I'm not interested in the path, but rather in all leaves of a DFS/BFS from a building complex downwards with specific properties. However, the leave nodes my have different depths, depending on how the indoor data was mapped.

I already tried my luck with the `>` and `>>` recursion operators, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach where we first identify all member ways of the relation, and then check all amenity=toilets in any of the closed ways therein.

```
rel[wikidata=Q835662];
way(r);
nwr(area)[amenity=toilets];
out center;
```

Answer (score 0):

So while playing around more with recursion filters, I found this working solution:

```
rel[wikidata=Q835662];
>>;
<;
>>;
way(bn)[amenity=toilets];
out body;
```

The recurse down, up, and back down feels a bit unnecessary to me, but I was unable to come up with a more efficient solution to traverse the graph from the building to the actual room (as described in the question).

I'll leave my question unanswered for another week or so in case someone has a better solution :)